# Remove part of a table with .detach

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I need a function that adds and removes a column in a table if a checkbox is checked or not. The code I got at the moment works fine to an extend. The console messages come up at the right time and the table column is correctly added to the HTML.

The problem lies in the `else{}` part: The columns are not removed when checkbox is unchecked. In firebug I get a message that my selector is wrong but I am not sure how to fix it. And assuming the selector was correct, is my application of `.detach(this)` correct?

```
 function makevisible(idsandclasses,object,folder){     
    $('#checkbox'+idsandclasses).change(function() {
      console.log(idsandclasses, "before if checked")

    if($('#checkbox'+idsandclasses).is(':checked')){
       console.log(idsandclasses, "if checked")
       $('tr:contains("Details")').append('<td id="rowdetails'+folder+'">'+object.name+'</td>')
       }else{
             console.log("unchecked")
             $('#rowdetails'+folder).detach(this)
             }  
    })
};
```

Here I use the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dot0001").hover(makevisible("info0001", object0001,"object0001"))
})
```

This is the firebug message:

TypeError: expr.replace is not a function
expr = expr.replace( rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" )

And this is the part in my jquery-1.9.0.js file my code has problems with:

```
expr = expr.replace( rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" );
```

I assumed there is no need for the HTML. If that should be the case though let me know.

Comment: This code calls `makevisible` and then passes the value returned (that is, `undefined`) to `.hover()`. That's not right. Either just call `makevisible`, or pass an actual function to `.hover()`.

Comment: To remove a column in a table, you have to remove the appropriate `<td>` in each row.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know thanks. Once I have an answer I know how to apply it to all cells. I just tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `this` from detach.  Just `.detach()` is sufficient.

Comment: But that does not solve the problem with the invalid selector

Comment: @Haley where is the invalid selector?  Because `$('#rowdetails'+folder)` should be a valid selector (should expand to `$("#rowdetailsobject0001")`

Comment: I added the firebug messsage to my question. Maybe that helps

Comment: What is `folder`?  Are you sure the detach line is the one with the error?

Comment: According to firebug the error message originates in my "jquery.1.9.0.js"

Comment: @Haley yeah but you can trace back the call stack to see where the error is in your own code

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the way I assign the id to the <td> a few lines earlier?

Comment: I had a look and added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a selector to `detach` (or nothing at all its optional).  You are passing `this` which is a DOM element.  Ideally, `$('#rowdetails'+folder)` will match the element you are trying to detach.

Source:

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the problem is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dot0001").hover(function(){
makevisible("info0001", object0001,"object0001")
})
})
```

Comment: If that would be the problem none of the console messages should come up, no?

Comment: Gave it a try. This makes my website really laggy and drives my mac´s process "WindowServer" to a crazy CPU usage.

Comment: ?! , any how here is few things that you should know .. 1st that `this` points to the same object that has the change function bound to it . is that a check ?